# Nancy Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, razor, nancy

I'm trying to display some information from a model to my view in Nancy.

### Viewmodel

```
public class Fixtures
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Users HomeUser { get; set; }
    public Users AwayUser { get; set; }
}
```

### Module

```
Get["/fixtures"] = _ =>
            {
                var model = new List<Fixtures>();

                model.Add(new Fixtures() { Id = 1, HomeUser = new Users() { id = 1, Name = "Paddy" }, AwayUser = new Users() { id = 2, Name = "Dave" } });
                model.Add(new Fixtures() { Id = 2, HomeUser = new Users() { id = 3, Name = "Scott" }, AwayUser = new Users() { id = 4, Name = "Chris" } });

                return View["Fixtures", model];
            };
```

### View

```
@inherits Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase<System.Collections.Generic.List<Fifa.Leaderboard.Data.ViewModel.Fixtures>>

@{

    Layout = "_Layout.cshtml";

}

<div id="fixtures">

    @foreach (var fixture in Model)

    {'

        <p>@fixture.HomeUser</p>

        <p>VS</p>

        <p>@fixture.AwayUser</p>

    }

</div>
```

Anyone know why I'm getting this error?

Comment: And where do you get the error? In which snippet of code?

Comment: i debugged it and go through the module, both the fixtures get added to the model variable. once I get to return View["Fixtures", model] it goes straight to the error, can't debug on the view for some reason

Comment: And this is the error? : Nancy Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: I'm using the nancy framework and the error is Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Sorry should have made it clearer

Comment: It's coming from `@{ Layout = "_Layout.cshtml"; } why would my layout cause this error?

Comment: The problem was I wasn't pointing to the correct place for my layout file should have been Layout = "Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";, thanks anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Problem was found as mentioned in comments of original question.*

Nancy does not have a concept of a Shared Views folder like ASP.NET MVC.

The normal way to do this would be to put the `_Layout.cshtml` in the root of the `/Views` folder.

If you want to avoid the view being in the root folder or avoid specifying the full path, you can add a View Location to the list like so:

```
public class CustomConventionsBootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ApplicationStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, Nancy.Bootstrapper.IPipelines pipelines)
    {
        this.Conventions.ViewLocationConventions.Add((viewName, model, context) =>
        {
            return string.Concat("views/shared/", viewName);
        });
    }
}
```

Documentation can be found here:

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/View-location-conventions#defining-custom-conventions